# I can't install gulp-typescript in my project

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I installed **typescript** & **gulp-typescript** globally and locally, even my **devDependencies** in **package.json** have `"gulp-typescript": "^3.1.6"` but when I write `gulp tsc` in cmd, it says: ***typescript is not installed - install with 'npm install typescript --save-dev'***

screenshot after run gulp:
[image: screenshot after run gulp]

screenshot after `npm install typescript --save-dev`:
[image: screenshot after <code>npm install typescript --save-dev</code>]

Comment: Can you show your `package.json`?

Comment: @AlekseyL 

`{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfiles.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Arman Shojaei",
  "license": "ISC"
}
`

Comment: Just change `"name": "typescript"` to something else e.g. `"name": "typescript-test"` and run `npm install`. You can't have package named as one of its dependencies.

Comment: @AlekseyL thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your package name `typescript` is same as the package you are trying to install. Change your package name in `package.json` to something other than `typescript`:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-something"
  // ...
}
```